# Create context initializer from existing database and .sql files

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database with data in it. There are (a lot of) sql files which insert a set of starting data.

The project is being refactored to code-first approach, so I wan't to move the init sql files into a context initializer.

Is there a way to achieve this with a tool or script, without having to manually re-type all the sql files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **EF Migration** to perform this kind of refactorization.

And on the migration, you can execute custom SQL scripts. Here is an example :
https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/46638380/execute-custom-sql-script-as-part-of-entity-framework-migration

Comment: Does the migration transfer records too, or just does the structural changes? The colums are not changing in any tables, I just need to move the seed data into a context initializer.

Comment: You can use migration without changing any of the database structure.
You can just use migrationBuilder.Sql("Your SQL Code") to insert/update/delete data.